# How to disable a button inside a nested Movie Clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, movieclip

I have a Movie Clip, lets call it A. Then inside A, i have another Movie Clip, lets call it B, then inside B, I have another Movie Clip , lets call it C, and inside C I have a several button that needs to be disabled temporarily. Is it possible? I have tried

```
A.B.C.enabled=false;
```

and

```
A.B.C.mouseEnabled=false;
```

That's not working. However i found a way to do it.

```
A.B.C.buttonInsideC.mouseEnabled=false;
```

But if I use it like that, I have to script it for all of the button, and I have a lot. So I think that would be a burden to my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only `mouseEnabled`, you have to disable [mouseChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren) property of C too.

```
A.B.C.mouseChildren = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a custom class to store your child MovieClip in, just have a function that checks if it is the correct child and if it isn't call the same function on the child. EG:

```
public class ClipMovie extends MovieClip
{
    private var _Child:ClipMovie;

    public function DisableButtonsAt(int childIndex, int currentIndex):void
    {
            if(childIndex + 1 == currentIndex)
            {
                someButton.mouseEnabled = false;
            }
            else if(_Child != null)
            {
                _Child.DisableButtonsAt(childIndex, currentIndex + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Error("Unable to find child, cannot disable buttons.");
            }
    }
}
```